# Multi-threaded Java console application for reading from database and updating REST server

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, java-threads

I have developed a Java console application which does the following;

1. Fetch Product details like Product Id, Name, cost etc from an Oracle database and put it in a map (say dbMap) - one product can have multiple records as there are sub products.
2. Fetch similar Product details from a REST server and store it in a map (say restMap)
3. Since the DB has the correct data, compares the two maps - dbMap and restMap and identifies what should be added, replaced and removed from the REST server.
4. For this purpose, I create one JSON patch request for each product - with add, replace, remove operations(around hundred or so for each product) and send it to REST server.

However, i see it takes a few minutes to perform all these operations and all these operations happen in a linear manner - the database call, the rest server call, the comparison and finally the Patch to REST server.

I am assuming, instead of tackling all the data in a single thread, if I can get a list of products and go product by product, with each product in its own thread and run these threads in parallel, it might be faster.

so, each thread might do the following - fetch product details of one product from database and also from REST server, compare them both and generate a patch request(with Add/remove/replace operations) for that product and send it to REST server.

Could you please suggest how I can implement this type of thread architecture in Java? (There seem to be several ways like threadpools, AKKA etc and I am confused.)

Comment: You are describing building and maintaining an API-accessible cache in front of your database. It may seem tempting to build your own cache, but it's probably not the correct path to pursue. There are things like [ehcache](https://www.ehcache.org/about/) that solve this (many others).

Answer (score 0):

Since dbCall and restCall are not mutually depended you can make  parallel calls in 2 Threads. And one dedicated  thread to process comparison.

You may use producer consumer approach here.

You can use Thread pools for same using Executor service:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: Thanks. If i do want to do in a different manner - do complete cycle for each product - db fetch for a product, rest fetch for a product, compare them for a product and push that to rest server, and i want to put this cycle in a thread - meaning , each thread for  a cycle where one cycle = one product processing, then in this case, can you please suggest a framework or pattern?